# clean vs. clobber

Tags: c++, compilation

I compile a big project:
I run a compilation and it fails with "unfinished jobs" error
When I make clean /clobber it fails in another place with the same error?

What is the difference between clean and clobber for compiling?
And how the problem descrined above cold be solved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Keith is right, clean and clobber can mean whatever the author of the makefile wants them to.

In practice though I think typically the difference between the two is this:

- `clean`: deletes all the object files created
- `clobber`: deletes all the object files AND the intermediate dependency files generated which specify the dependencies of the cpp files.

At least that has been the case in the projects I have worked on.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're saying that you run the command

```
make clean
```

or

```
make clobber
```

These are targets specified in your `Makefile`.  Their meaning is determined by what the Makefile says; they're not predefined.  Typically they'd both remove files (executables, object files) generated when you compile.  The difference, if any, between `clean` and `clobber` depends on the whim of the author of the `Makefile`.